# MySQL insert with unknown ID's

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

Is it possible to insert data with a specific id that is unknown while the reference to that id is known?

Example:

I got a car type and I know the name but I don't know the ID of it.

In the database it known as: FooBarCar 13

Now I want to insert FooBarCar in some reference table but I dont know the id yet. Is it possible to write this into one query/subquery or do I have to select this first in a separate query? If it is possible with one query/subquery can it be done with multiple unknown 'cars'?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_a(`Name`,`cID`,`another_field`) 
VALUES('Something',
(SELECT id FROM table_b tb WHERE tb.cat = '5'),
'somethingelse')
```

Source: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76538

Comment: How would this be done with multiple unknown / rows to be inserted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one query with `INSERT INTO`

```
INSERT INTO CARTBL (carname, cartype ) 
VALUES (
    'mycar',
    (select cartypeid from CARTYPETBL where typename='cartype')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_ref (id, value)
SELECT id, 'give_value'
FROM table_car
WHERE type = 'given_type'
```

This can handle multiple inserts aswell in one query.

Comment: Could you give an example of the multiple version? And I assume that 'give_value' is replaced with the result of type = 'given_type'?

Comment: 'give_value' is basicly a string which will be inserted in the `value` column. I do the inserts from `table_car` by filtering type with 'given_type'. It's very similiar to an ordinary `SELECT`.